# Cheap way of flying from mainland Europe to the Faroe Islands?

Tags: air-travel, budget, europe, faroe-islands, eclipses

[A solar eclipse is scheduled to pass over the Faroe Islands](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Solar_eclipse_of_March_20,_2015) and this seems like an excellent chance to visit.

What is a cheap way of flying there from mainland Europe? Kayak seems to only find ridiculous $2,000 fares to Sorvagur airport.

Comment: Yeah I've  been hunting too.  It's absurd. Your arguably better bet is to fly to Longyearbyen from Oslo ($500ish). THe trouble is the flight times, you may have to sleep in the airport.  Both Faroe and Longyearbyen have completely sold out of accommodation, and it's too cold to camp :/

Comment: I know that's not what you're asking for, but if you have time, you could take the [ferry](http://www.smyrilline.com/the-journey/route-denmark-faroe-islands-(and-return)/prices-2015/ferry-prices) from Denmark which for that season starts from 129 Euro a person one-way (check the on foot prices).

Comment: @drat I'll accept the ferry answer as well if it's significantly cheaper than flying :)

Comment: The ferry line offers an [eclipse cruise](http://www.smyrilline.com/destinations/faroe-islands/total-solar-eclipse-2015) that seems to include accommodation while on the islands, _plus_ an attempt to sail for clear skies in case of a cloudy forecast.

Comment: I wonder if there's not going to be a pretty significant camping scene there though just for this event? The ferry ticket and winter camping gear together will still be cheaper than the flight and I bet there will be some pretty interesting people camping there and having some kind of eclipse party.

Comment: @drat that ferry option interests me too..nice find.

Comment: I think the cruise @HenningMakholm mentions will actually be your best shot, especially if accommodation sells out. It's the same company as I mentioned, but they'll deviate their normal schedule for the event to leave Faroe Islands only on Friday night and they will stay there as a "floating hotel" during the week.

Comment: Kayak is the cheapest ;-)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The only airline with regular scheduled flights to the Faroe Islands is [Atlantic Airways](https://www.atlantic.fo/), the flag carrier. There are daily flights to/from Copenhagen and less frequently to/from Keflavik, Bergen and Billund.

However, they are probably already fully booked for the days near the eclipse ...

Your best bet may be to find a dedicated eclipse tour with a chartered flight.

Comment: It looks like there is also at least one dedicated eclipse cruise for a lot cheaper than $2,000.